# How is the charge conserved at the up to anti-down vertex?

Tags: particle-physics, charge, standard-model, feynman-diagrams, quarks

[image: GIM mechanism]

I can see how the charge is conserved in the overall diagram but I can not understand how it is conserved at the up to anti-down vertex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your diagrams, time moves to the right.  The four vertices that make up the "box" aren't well-ordered in time.  So the vertex involving the anti-down is one of the reactions

$$
\bar d u \to W^+ \qquad\text{or}\qquad \bar d \to \bar u W^+
$$

These vertices conserve both electric charge and baryon number.